# Adding audio to a video

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, webrtc

I am trying to do a website which will record your video, remove the audio and add an audio to the uploaded video.

I did the recording (without audio) using html5, and I uploaded the video to the server, so now I have video without audio, but what I cant figure, is how to add the audio to this video.

Please notice, all the videos uploaded are 10 seconds, and the audio also 10 seconds.

Comment: you need to do something like this http://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg

Comment: @simone.sanfratello unfortunately dont have ffmpeg enabled

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Try getting a basic VPS where you can install everything you would want. However, if you know your (most definitely shared hosting's) operating system (I bet it's Linux), you can just download a static binary, upload it to your app folder and call the command line though your app.

Comment: In the end, you probably want a VPS anyway for the sake of performance. Imagine everybody running ffmpeg on a shared hosting...

Answer (score 0):

You can download FFmpeg static builds here: http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Just upload the one suitable for your servers' OS (most definitely Linux) to your servers' app folder. When you set permissions to 700, you can just call the command line tool from your application.

#### Basic PHP Example

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('./ffmpeg');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way to do it.

Comment: 700 will only work if Apache/PHP runs with the same user has the one who uploaded the file. And if this works (I mean, authorizing the execution of any binary), I would highly recommend to run away from that hosting because it could involve serious security issues.

Comment: @Capsule That's what policies do, not a security risk, just working as intended......

Comment: @Kevin It's not a security issue to authorize any uploaded binary to be executed by any user on a shared hosting? Well well well...

Comment: @Capsule Who said anything about a user uploading the binary?? "download FFmpeg static builds", so that's actively going to that url from the server, so only the server admin could ever do this.

Comment: @Kevin, herrbischoff did: *Just upload the one suitable for your servers' OS (most definitely Linux) to your servers' app folder*

Comment: @Capsule Ah I didn't read that, sorry. Then again, if a user is allowed to even upload a binary to the "servers' app folder", chances are he is allowed to run anything on the server anyway.

Comment: That's how some WordPress plugins do their work, for example image compression. It's perfectly normal behavior as you usually cannot access anything outside of your folder and privilege escalation is disabled.

Comment: That's theory. You could upload a binary exploiting a vulnerability on a lower level and end up running it as root. That's why it's never a good idea to allow that. YES, you should patch your system but until the vulnerability is discovered and patched, you're at risk. Not to mention the performance issues. Anyway, who wants to be on a shared hosting anymore these days? ;-)

Comment: @Capsule: True. But if you look around, every shared hosting account allowed me to run binaries via the method described. Then again, shared hosting is really just for simple web sites, not applications.

Comment: Most shared hosting are sh*** anyway, that would explain why they don't really care about security nor performance. Slow or hacked? They will reply "You should have gone the VPS route"

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. And one that's come up before. We developed [www.api.audio](http://www.api.audio) to do audio-as-a-service infrastructure, and one use case that comes up a lot is the 'adding voiceovers' or 'adding audio' to a video.

https://docs.api.audio/recipes/create-a-voice-over-for-your-video you can see the example here, with examples in Javascript and in python.